# Pass a foreign key to partial render in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, render, partial

I'm trying to pass the foreign key from one view to another using partial render. However there is a problem in passing the local variable because only the last record get to be displayed.

Gist link: https://gist.github.com/ReemAlattas/5d08b0b60fc890540c7b

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: does it trigger some errors?

Comment: each loop is right? never seen that one before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `_select.html.erb` file you should fix this row (previously used @p_id seems to be nil):

```
<% @kpis.each do |kpi| if kpi.plan_id == p_id %>
```

and in `index.html.erb` you are passing to the partial a symbol `:p_id` against the `p_id` value, let replace it with:

```
<%= render :partial => "kpis/select", locals: {plan_id: p_id} %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<% @kpis.each do |kpi| if kpi.plan_id == plan_id %>
```